# What is “abnd” on the U.S. VFR Sectional Chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

I have looked at the sectional legend and FAA aeronautical chart user guides and have not seen any answer for this.

What is [“abnd”](https://skyvector.com/?ll=31.258991096942665,-98.54352641206222&chart=32&zoom=1) on the U.S. VFR Sectional Chart?

[image: abnd]

Comment: It's not on the abbrevations list, but I would assume that it is indicating that the railway is an abandoned line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ABND, according to the United States of America Aeronautical Contractions means:

**Abandon**

A link to this document can be found here: 
[FAA Website](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/Basic7340.2A.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Or more precisely, "abandoned".

Answer (score 8):

That example is a railroad, and it is "abandon**ed**".   That means it won't make a very good Iron Compass, as it is won't have the impeccable tree trimming, clean ballast and weed spraying that makes railroads so visible normally.

It may well be that the rails are in place and is merely embargoed, little-used or in preservation, but that is of little concern to aviators.

Of concern is that the indicated river bridge, that you've been using as a landmark, [may not be there anymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinzua_Bridge).